# Numpy 1D-array operation in a ND-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say we have a 4D-array A of shape (n, m, g, h) and a 1D-array B of shape (n).

So I want to do a power operation for every 3D sub-array of A (m, g, h) with every element of B (which is an int).

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape(3, 2, 2, 2)
>>>array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[16, 17],
         [18, 19]],

        [[20, 21],
         [22, 23]]]]
B = np.arange(3)
>>>array([0, 1, 2])
```

The result that I want is:

```
C = somefunc(A, B) # just an example, can be anything
>>>array([[[[ (ignore, 0^0),  1],
         [ 1,  1]],

        [[ 1,  1],
         [ 1,  1]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[256, 289],
         [324, 361]],

        [[400, 441],
         [484, 529]]]]
```

What is the best way to get the desired result?

I thought about something like:

```
A = [np.power(A[i, :, :, :], B[i]) for i in range(B.size)]
```

But that would be quite inefficient if B.size is a big number. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is inefficient of `A = [np.power(A[i, :, :, :], b) for b in B)]` ? The `a**b` is necessary even if `b` is big.

Comment: `np.power(A, B[:,None,None,None])` - that is, expand the dimensions of `B` so it broadcasts with `A`.

Comment: Or `(A.T**B).T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
C = A ** B[:,None,None,None]
print (C)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[[  1   1]
   [  1   1]]

  [[  1   1]
   [  1   1]]]


 [[[  8   9]
   [ 10  11]]

  [[ 12  13]
   [ 14  15]]]


 [[[256 289]
   [324 361]]

  [[400 441]
   [484 529]]]]
```